# What does the Ruby operator == do in this case?

Tags: ruby

I'm currently looking at a [piece of code from the excellent Rails-composer](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-composer/blob/28855c7a55a2773188d03f5e40d2d35efe35fb28/files/app/views/layouts/_messages-bootstrap.html.erb) and I don't understand what the Embedded Ruby in the 3rd line does:

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
  <% if msg.is_a?(String) %>
    <div class="alert alert-<%= name == :notice ? "success" : "error" %>">
      <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&#215;</a>
      <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I've looked at the [Ruby documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/) with no luck so far. Once I understand how this code works I'd like to extend it to support all levels of `flash[]` messages.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use the conditional operator (? :) in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252936/how-do-i-use-the-conditional-operator-in-ruby)

Comment: Maybe this links is useful:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151410/c-sharp-auto-highlight-text-in-a-textbox-control

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the [**Ternary Operator**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#Ruby).

```
(condition) ? "true value" : "false value"
```

It's saying if `name == :notice` use `"success"` otherwise `"error"`.

Comment: The link to Wikipedia doesn't want to work so replace `?` with `%3F` in the URL.

Answer (score 2):

This line

```
result = (name == :notice ? "success" : "error")
```

Can be tanslated to:

```
result =""
if(name == :notice)
{
 result = "success"
}
else
{
 result = "error"
}
```

In your case the result is not a variable, but it's value is pasted to html.

**EDIT**

> I'd like to extend it to support all levels of flash[] messages.

This operator is usually used just for simple true false condition, though if you really want you can use it like that:

```
name == :notice ? "success" : name == :error ? "error" : "something else"
```

Consider using this instead (more readable)

```
if name == :notice
 "success"
elsif name == :error
 "error"
else
 "something else"
end
```

Comment: Hi @gisek, I wish I could have awared 2 answers to my question. Really appreciated yours as well.

Answer (score 1):

That code changes the div class dynamically. It checks for :notice and the div class will get:

- "alert alert-success"
- "alert alert-error"

depending of :notice result.

Answer (score 0):

It's displaying the contents of the flash. Each key-value pair of the flash is displayed as a separate div, with the class of the div depending on the key.

Line 3 is adding a class of alert-success or alert-failure depending on whether the key is :notice or not