# How to enable copy when textbox.enabled is false?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `TextBox` control and want to be able to copy content of `TextBox`.

Properties of `TextBox` look like this;

```
textBox1.Enabled = false;
textBox1.ReadOnly = false;
```

I cannot copy content of textBox1 even though ReadOnly property is false.

Is there any suggestion?

Comment: Have you tried setting `enabled` to `true` ?

Comment: I miss some point, If I set ReadOnly as true, is there any importance of Enabled property?

Comment: @MehmetInce:- I have covered that point in my answer!

Comment: Thanks for your all answer. @Rahul special thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ýou may try this if you want the user to allow copy paste:

```
textBox1.ReadOnly = true;
```

From [MSDN forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e3999a28-9923-457f-b52a-96c91059e455/readonly-vs-enabled?forum=Vsexpressvcs)

> In the context of a TextBox, readonly allows the user to set focus to
>   and select and copy the text but not modify it. A disabled TextBox
>   does not allow any interaction whatsoever.
>
> Use ReadOnly when you have data that you want the user to see and
>   copy, but not modify. Use a disabled textbox, when the data you are
>   displaying is not applicable in for the current state of a dialog or
>   window.

Comment: @MehmetInce:- Also to add:- When you make a control as **disabled** it cannot be edited and its content is excluded when the form is submitted.

When you make as  control is **readonly** it cannot be edited, but its content (if any) is still included with the submission.

Comment: Couple tips on readonly textbox+copy to clipboard: 1: You can also override the background color to make it white again/etc. 2: I also recommend select all on a 'onclick' event. So data copied is highlighted. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/2151429/503621

Answer (score 5):

You should set your textboxes to `ReadOnly = true` instead of `Enabled = false` if you want to support copy/paste.

Answer (score 4):

```
textBox1.ReadOnly = true;
```

you can even use a copy button and code as follows:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetText(textBox1.Text);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <input type="text" id="txtMobileNo" runat="server" onkeypress="return onlyNos(event,this);" class="form-control input-sm m-bot15" readonly="readonly" maxlength="10" style="font-weight: bold; background-color: #ecf9ec" tabindex="0" />
```

use  readonly="readonly" in textbox code