# Method to highlighting Text in TextBox is inconsistent

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

Currently I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151410/c-sharp-auto-highlight-text-in-a-textbox-control) method to highlight text inside a TextBox, but it works just sometimes.

This code has to verify if there is contained a space in the entered text. If there is a space in the text the user should be warned, and then the text inside the TextBox has to be highlighted:

```
if (textBox.Text.Contains(" "))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Sorry, the value entered must not contain any spaces.", "Please enter a valid value", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);

    //Highlights incorrect text
    textBox.SelectionStart = 0;
    textBox.SelectionLength = textBox.Text.Length;
}
```

Why isn't this method working for me all the time and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Please consider using a simple keypress javascript event to cancel any spaces the user puts in...  makes a much better user experience.

Comment: @Eric I think it's a problem of focusing.

Comment: Valadate and DataError are much better user experiences.  Message box is very obtrusive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be a problem when you are selecting length of textBox which has no focus in current moment.

Can you try to add check for focus?

```
if (textBox.Text.Contains(" "))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Sorry, the value entered must not contain any spaces.", "Please enter a valid value", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);

    if(!textBox.Focused)
    {
      textBox.Focus();
    }

    //Highlights incorrect text
    textBox.SelectionStart = 0;
    textBox.SelectionLength = textBox.Text.Length;
}
```

Also instead of current solution you can use textBox.SelectAll():

```
if (textBox.Text.Contains(" "))
{
    textBox.SelectAll();
    MessageBox.Show("Sorry, the value entered must not contain any spaces.", "Please enter a valid value", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);

}
```

Comment: The c# code would be `if(!textBox.Focus())`. I tried it, it worked once and I was hopeful, but then on the other attempts it failed...

Comment: Can you describe in which cases it fails?

Comment: Actually you should not call Focus method if element already has focus. So check if textbox.Focused - makes sens.

Comment: Never mind, it's working now. It was my fault. But just for clarity, when I use `textBox.Focused` it says that `textBox` does not contain a definition for `Focused`.

Comment: Ah, ok. And what about textBox.SelectAll() method? Does it exist?

Comment: Yep, textBox.SelectAll() exists.

Comment: Than you can use SelectAll instead of your code, I think it should even set focus.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56228/discussion-between-eric-after-dark-and-u10).