# How do I highlight the text in a textbox at the startup of a window?

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I asked a question similar to this a few days ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24394304/method-to-highlighting-text-in-textbox-is-inconsistent). The answer works fine, with the exception of performing the same operation at the start up of the window. This means that I need to have the text in a `textBox` highlighted every time the window is opened.

Currently I am setting the focus to the `textBox` at startup with no problem in the constructor. With that being said, I am guessing that the correct area to perform this operation is in the constructor. This is what I am trying currently with no luck:

```
public AddDestination()
{
     InitializeComponent();

     //Give cursor focus to the textbox
     destination_textBox.Focus();

     //Highlights text **DOES NOT WORK
     destination_textBox.SelectionStart = 0;
     destination_textBox.SelectionLength = destination_textBox.Text.Length;
}
```

How can I make it so that the text inside my `textBox` is highlighted whenever the window opens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of constructor, move it to AddDestination_Load event.

```
     public AddDestination()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void AddDestination_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Give cursor focus to the textbox
        textBox1.Focus();

        //Highlights text **DOES NOT WORK
        textBox1.SelectionStart = 0;
        textBox1.SelectionLength = textBox1.Text.Length;

    }
```

Comment: Cool. With that being said, in terms of xaml, where do I set `Load` in the window?

Comment: you've got me here. I just double clicked a form and it wired all the events for me.

Comment: This is in wpf. I have an event for `Loaded` in the title section of the xaml window.

Comment: I did and it worked =D. With that being said, you might just want to make sure you change the event to `Loaded`.

Answer (score 1):

You can write this segment of code in Load EventHandler

```
//code
InitializeComponent();
//code

private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //Give cursor focus to the textbox
     destination_textBox.Focus();

     //Highlights text **DOES NOT WORK
     destination_textBox.SelectionStart = 0;
     destination_textBox.SelectionLength = destination_textBox.Text.Length;
}
```

To do so go to **Designer**, click on the window, go to **Properties**, click **Events** button, search for **Load** event then double-click on it.