# How to highlight the control when it gets focus?

Tags: c#, winforms, selectall

I can highlight the text in an individual MaskedTextBox when it gets focus using:

```
this.myTextBox.SelectAll();
```

But, I want to do it for all MaskedTextBox when a mouse click event occurs.  Instead of adding 30 individual event method for each MaskedTextbox, I want to select all MaskedTextBox and have one event method to take care of it, ie:

```
private void MouseClickedForMaskedTextBox(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    this.ActiveControl.SelectAll();
}
```

But SelectAll is not available for this.ActiveControl.  Is there a way to get around it?

Comment: Create a usercontrol that inherits from textbox, put a static method or property on it, proceeed from there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sender` will be the target of the event.

You could cast `sender`:

```
MaskedTextBox maskedTextBox = sender as MaskedTextBox;
if (maskedTextBox != null) { maskedTextBox.SelectAll(); }
```

Or in  C# 7,

```
if (sender is MaskedTextBox maskedTextBox) 
{
    maskedTextBox.SelectAll();
}
```

Another improvement is to use `TextBoxBase` and it will work with `TextBox` and `RichTextBox` as well.

Comment: In 1st option, it errors "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox' to 'bool'.  In 2nd option, it causes 3 errors ") expected" at end of MaskedTextBox, "; expected" at end of maskedTextBox, and "} expected" at end of maskedTextBox.

Comment: After playing around with your 1st option, I removed the "if" condition, and it works!!!!  Thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: @itchibahn i fixed the condition - my javascript was showing.

Answer (score 1):

Put the following code in the form's constructor:

```
        foreach (Control c in Controls)
        {
            if (c is TextBox)
            {
                TextBox tb = c as TextBox;
                tb.GotFocus += delegate { tb.SelectAll(); };
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply do that:

```
private void maskedTextBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker) delegate() {
   maskedTextBox1.SelectAll();
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another way by creating or edit your User Control that inherits MaskedTextBox. In the designer you set true the property "OnEnterSelectAll".

```
public partial class MaskedTextBoxX : MaskedTextBox
{
    public MaskedTextBoxX()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Inicializar();
        }

    // ===============================
    // Campos Añadidos
    // ===============================

    public bool OnEnterSelectAll { get; set; } = false;


    // ===============================
    // Metodos
    // ===============================

    private void Inicializar()
    {
        // *** SELECCIONAR TODO el MarkedTextBox
        Click += delegate { if (OnEnterSelectAll) SelectAll(); };
    }
}
```